Camera capture stopped working after upgrading from Expo SDK 50 -> 51
So I just upgraded from SDK 50 -> 51 which made my app crash all the time I go to component with a Camera, now i fixed it, my current "take picture" method does not work. Do you guys know how to fix this?
const captureImage = async () => {
        if (camRef) {
            try {
                const imgData = await camRef.current.takePictureAsync({
                    base64: false,
                    imageType: ImageType.png,
                });

                setImage(imgData);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }

I tried using other methods but doesnt work

the recording function that you mentioned in the question works well, it would be great if you can share the cameraView component to see the options you have passed there it might be an issue in that component.

This example worked for me:
async function takePicture() {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({
        base64: false,
        imageType:ImageType.png,
        onPictureSaved: async (picture) => {
          console.log('Picture saved:', picture.uri)
          setImage(picture.uri as string);
          const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(picture.uri);
        }
      });

    }
  }

        <CameraView ref={cameraRef} style={styles.camera} facing={type as CameraType}>
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={toggleCameraType}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Flip Camera {selectedRatio}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={takePicture}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Take Picture</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{
              flex: 1, width: 100, height: 100, alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', resizeMode: 'contain'
            }} />}
          </View>
        </CameraView>


i was using expo-face-detector but as it is not working in expo SDK 51, and react-native-vision-camera  how do I implement face detection?

this is out of scope of this question, can you open a new question and I will be happy to help you there.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78637094/native-modulereact-native-showing-black-screen-when-integrating-camera   please help me out

did you try to check this: https://react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/frame-processors#creating-native-frame-processor-plugins I would not be able to help you beyond that, the question you created is a bit different than this one and I can not help you there.
